# Не проходят тесты, NullPointerException

Tags: java

При прохождении 9 теста , выдаёт

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at QueueImpl$IteratorImpl.remove(QueueImpl.java:90)
at QueueImpl.test9(QueueImpl.java:354)
at QueueImpl.main(QueueImpl.java:133)
```

Немогу понять в чем причина. Тесты дал преподаватель.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class QueueImpl implements Queue {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    int current = 0;

    @Override
    public void enqueue(Object element)
    {
        Node a = new Node();
        a.element = element;

        if (tail == null) {
            head = a;
            tail = a;
        } else {
            tail.next = a;
            a.prev = tail;
            tail = a;
        }
        current++;
    }

    @Override
    public Object dequeue() {
        Node element = head;
        head = element.next;
        current--;
        return element.element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        return head.element;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        current = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return current;
    }

    public static class Node {
        Object element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    public class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {

        Node iteratorImpl = head;
        Node follow;
        private int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iteratorImpl != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            index++;
            follow = iteratorImpl;
            iteratorImpl = iteratorImpl.next;
            return follow.element;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove()
        {
            Node prev = follow.prev;
            Node next = follow.next;

            if (index == 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            if (prev != null)
                prev.next = follow.next;

            if (next != null)
                next.prev = follow.prev;

            if (follow == head)
                head = next;
            index--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.next == null) {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element).append(", ");
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
        test2();
        test3();
        test4();
        test5();
        test6();
        test7();
        test8();
        test9();
        test10();
    }

    public static void test1() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        Class c = queue.getClass();
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces().length);

        // must be Queue
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

        // must be Container
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

        // must be java.lang.Iterable
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getName());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * 1 Queue 1 Container 1 java.lang.Iterable
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test2() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        queue.clear();
        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");

        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * [A, B, C] 3 [] 0 [A, B, C] 3
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test3() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test4() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        for (Object element : queue) {
            System.out.print(element);
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test5() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println();
        it = queue.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next());
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC ABC
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test6() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A B C []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test7() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A B C [A, B] A [B] B []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test8() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        try {
            it.remove();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A exception
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test9() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        try {
            it.remove();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * exception
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test10() {
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        System.out.println(queue.top());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A
         *************************************
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас вот в этом методе `public void remove()` вот в этой строчке `Node prev = follow.prev;` переменая `follow` на что указывает?

Comment: @tym32167 На текущий элемент.

Comment: А он у вас есть в момент вызова, этот текущий элемент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        if (index == 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        Node prev = follow.prev;
        Node next = follow.next;

        if (prev != null)
            prev.next = follow.next;

        if (next != null)
            next.prev = follow.prev;

        if (follow == head)
            head = next;
        index--;
    }
```